# i can't migrate my wordpress site because my the current hosting is failing

Tags: wordpress, migration, hosting

I can't migrate my wordpress site because my current hosting is failing in the process.
migration plugin just won't work... I tried doing it manually by downloading all the files via ftp but it is failing somewhere at the end...

any ideas what can I do?

Comment: Can you provide more details regarding you hosting options and the error stack?

Comment: my hosting is infinity free, when I'm trying to transfer the files with FTP it is just disconnecting in the middle